# Looping through Dictionary Transforms Type to List

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a simple dictionary in python. For each item in the dictionary, I have another dictionary I need to attach to each line (i.e. 5 contacts, each contact has FirstName, LastName, Gender, plus 'other' fields which all fall in single embedded dictionary.

I have attached the loop I am using. The resulting output is exactly how I want it, but when I run a type() function on it, Python reads it as a list rather than a dictionary. How can I convert it back to a dictionary?

```
itemcount = 0
for item in dict_primarydata:
    dict_primarydata[itemcount]['otherData'] = dict_otherdata[itemcount]
    itemcount = itemcount+1
```

Comment: iterating over `dict_primarydata` only looks at the keys. use `dict_primarydata.items()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a guess and say `dict_primarydata` and `dict_otherdata` look something like this to start out:

```
dict_primarydata = [
  {
    'first_name': 'Kaylee',
    'last_name': 'Smith',
    'gender': 'f'
  },
  {
    'first_name': 'Kevin',
    'last_name': 'Hoyt',
    'gender': 'm'
  }
]

dict_otherdata = [
  {
    'note': 'Note about kaylee'
  },
  {
    'note': 'Note about kevin'
  }
]
```

It looks like `dict_primarydata` and `dict_otherdata` are initialized as lists of dicts. In other words, `dict_primarydata` is not actually a dict; it's a list containing several dicts.

If you want your output to be a `dict` containing `dict`s you need to perform a conversion. Before you can do the conversion, you need to decide what you will use as key to your outer dict.

### Sidenote

Since you are iterating over two lists. A range-based for loop would be a bit more readable:

```
for i in range(len(dict_primarydata)):
    dict_primarydata[i]['otherData'] = dict_otherdata[i]
```